# Why won't my sub using the .Copy method grab both reference ranges unless I run the sub twice?

Tags: vba, excel

I have cobbled together a subroutine to get two ranges of data from blocks of cells in two separate worksheets. Then, using the `.Copy` method, it puts the first block into `(1, 1)` of a third worksheet and the second block into the next available row of that worksheet.

The code I have written pretty much does what I want it to do, except that for some reason it will not paste the second range (declared as `DataRng2` below) unless the sub is run twice in a row. Here is what I have:

```
Sub Test()

Dim DataRng As Range
Dim DataRng2 As Range
Dim Test As Worksheet
Dim EmtyRow As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Test = Worksheets("Test")
'Set the "EmptyRow" reference to whatever the next empty row is in the destination worksheet -     checks column A
Set EmptyRow = Worksheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Select all utilized cells in 82-Medicine tab and copy them
Worksheets("82-Medicine").Select
Set DataRng = Worksheets("82-Medicine").Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
'Select the destination worksheet and paste copied cells to A1
Test.Select
DataRng.Copy Cells(1, 1)

'Select all utilized cells in Fee Basis tab and copy them
Worksheets("Fee Basis").Select
Set DataRng2 = Worksheets("Fee Basis").Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
'Select the destination worksheet and paste copied cells to the next empty row
Test.Select
DataRng2.Copy EmptyRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Why do I have to run it twice to get it to work? Is there a way to fix that?

I should note that I am using the `.CurrentRegion` property to get the data only because rows of data will frequently be added to and subtracted from the ranges of cells I need to grab, and `.CurrentRegion` is the simplest way I know to grab the first range of whatever cells are occupied. I am open to using a different property or method if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim src_1       As Worksheet
    Dim src_2       As Worksheet
    Dim dest        As Worksheet
    Dim src_1_rng   As Range
    Dim src_2_rng   As Range
    Dim lr          As Integer
    Dim lc          As Integer

    Set src_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("82-Medicine")
    Set src_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FeeBasis")
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

    '' Set up range for data from '82-Medicine'
    lr = src_1.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    lc = src_1.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Set src_1_rng = src_1.Range(src_1.Cells(2, 1), src_1.Cells(lr, lc))

    '' Set up range for data from 'FeeBasis'
    lr = src_2.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    lc = src_2.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Set src_2_rng = src_2.Range(src_2.Cells(2, 1), src_2.Cells(lr, lc))

    '' Copy the data to the destination sheet ('Test')
    src_1_rng.Copy dest.Range("A" & dest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    src_2_rng.Copy dest.Range("A" & dest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Not sure why that wouldn't work but try this. I've never been a fan of `CurrentRegion` or selecting different sheets during code. Why bother when you can just use references? This should work perfectly.

*edit*
Changed the lr and lc variables to use xlDown from (2,1) and xlToRight from (2,1) to properly get a "CurrentRegion"-esque range.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! Quick follow-up question: is there a way I could get it to ignore certain cells in the ranges it is copying from - say, for example, cells with `Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)`? I do not want those to be copied. They were outside of the `CurrentRegion` so the old code was effectively ignoring them, but this new code is just grabbing any and all occupied rows/columns.

Comment: Ah that's a good point. I didn't write the `lr` and `lc` variables appropriately. Give me one second.

Comment: Try what I just posted, that should be more accurate